# ASP.Net Map Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, bing-maps

I want to add a map control to my website (ASP.Net 4.0, Visual Studio 2010) and have come across a few:

Bing Maps, Google Maps, OpenStreetMaps

The problems I am coming across is lack of good documentation for them.

I don't need anything too complicated (no routing or anything like that), I simply need to be able to add pins in locations.

I have used Bing Maps for Silverlight and it was great, it had a nice .Net control with lot's of documentation available, this is the sort of thing I am after for my ASP.Net site.

Has anyone any experience with ASP and Maps, and any code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does depend on what *exactly* your site is for, an dhow visible it is, etc.

For simple things like a "find our office" type of map to go on a public website, it's pretty easy, and generally free. For use on non-publically accessible sites, most vendors will charge (obviously OpenStreetMap won't).

For Bing Maps, there is even a handy little ASP.Net control [over on Codeplex](http://bingmapsasp.codeplex.com/), although I can't vouch for how good it is.

Comment: Yeah, I had found that link. There is no download for the control however (hence my annoyance leading to asking this question) - they are "currently planning a Version 1 release" and there is nothing on the download page. I am simply wanting to add multiple pins to a map using postcodes, and a lovely .Net control would be perfect (like the Silverlight control).

Comment: You should be able to [download the source](http://bingmapsasp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) - from what I understand, this is the code that was a CTP release form Microsoft, but it got canned before being made a real product. There is a link from that page to another product (trial available) as well. Perhaps if you explain further what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to provide examples for using one of the AJAX APIs